# Как исправить ошибку при установке nltk?

Tags: python, nltk

> MacBook-Air-1:~ a1$ sudo pip install -U nltk
> WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
> or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
> typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.
> To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

> Password:
> sudo: pip: command not found
> MacBook-Air-1:~ a1$ pip install nltk
> -bash: pip: command not found

Comment: нету инсталлятора `pip`

Comment: python3 get-pip.py